# cheap shadow in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is it possible to cast a static shadow in SceneKit? Don't know if static is the right word. I would only like a smooth black circle underneath my object when it falls. The object moves in y- and x-direction. I know that I can use `sampleRadius` property but that has a significant impact on performance. I have seen such thing in other game engines and I am wondering if I can achieve it in SceneKit too.

EDIT:

I used this, but I only ge black scene with very little lightning. It looks like that floor is completely black. I have tried different gobo images, but no luck. What have I missed?

```
    let spotNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("spot", recursively: true)
    let spotlight = spotNode?.light
    spotlight?.categoryBitMask = 1
    spotlight!.shadowMode = SCNShadowMode.Modulated
    spotlight?.gobo?.contents = UIImage(named: "goboImage")
    floorNode?.categoryBitMask = 1
```

//Apple code:

```
// Use modulated mode
light.shadowMode = SCNShadowModeModulated;

// Configure the projected shadow 
light.gobo.contents = aShadowImage;

// Use bit masks to specify receivers 
light.categoryBitMask = kProjectorLightMask; 
floor.categoryBitMask = kProjectorLightMask;
```

Comment: "Blob shadow" is the term I've seen most.

Answer (score 2):

you'll want to use the `SCNShadowModeModulated` shadow mode. The different techniques for shadows are explained in depth in the [Building a Game with SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-610/) presentation from WWDC 2014.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I edited my question with what I have now.

Comment: the default `categoryBitMask` for `SCNNode` instances is already `1`, so the light and the floor are not tied together. Try `0x2` or any bitmask such that `bitmask & 0x1 == 0x0`

Comment: I tried 0x1 for both the floor and light, 0x1 for the light and 0x2 for floor, 0x2 for both...It always results in entirely black floor. Not entirely sure what 0x1 notation represents though..

Answer (score 1):

---

General on this:

The `categoryBitMask` represents "categories".
So when you set a `categoryBitMask` on a light you are saying "*This light will only hit objects in this category*"

Ex:

```
static let WorldCategory: Int = 1 << 0 // Category for background objects
static let GameObjectsCat: Int = 1 << 1 // Category for monsters in the game :)

...
// When setting up the lights
spotlight.categoryBitMask = GameObjectsCat // Light will only affect game objects
spotlight.castsShadow = true

...

// Pretend this is a SCNNode representing a 3d fortress...
// Will not be affected the by spotlight or project it's shadows
fortress.categoryBitMask = WorldCategory

// Pretend this is a SCNNode representing a evil 3d monster...
// Affected by spotlight and projects shadows
orc.categoryBitMask = GameObjectsCat  
orc.castsShadow = true
```

That was the general take on `categoryBitMask`.

In your case we want to:

1. Create a modulated light (`SCNShadowMode.Modulated`)
2. Set the `gobo` image
3. Give light and floor the same `categoryBitMask` but make sure it is not set for any other node (like game characters or whatever). Tip would be to create a new category like `static let SimpleShadow: Int = 1 << 2`

This light will not illuminate anything in the scene (not even the floor), it will only project your `gobo` where ever it is pointed. So a second light source is needed to see something (Ambient will be easiest).

I have not had the possibility to test this out, so I am writing from what I remember. :)

But please note. With proper use of `categoryBitMask` you could easily create a "special light" designed to project a real shadow of your main character against the floor node. This would be very cheap, as the shadow would only be calculated for one single node, projected against one single node.

Hope this will help.